# How to programmatically configure rowSelect event listener for dataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have created a dataTable and associated context menu in backing bean but don't know how to configure rowSelect event listener. Here is part of the code:

```
DataTable table = (DataTable) application.createComponent(DataTable.COMPONENT_TYPE);
table.setValue(model);
table.setSelectionMode("single");
table.setVar("item");
table.setId("tableId");
                :

    ContextMenu ctxMenu = new ContextMenu();
    ctxMenu.setFor("tableId");

    DynamicMenuModel ctxModel = new DynamicMenuModel();

    ctxMenu.setModel(ctxModel);

    rightCenterPanel.getChildren().add(ctxMenu);
    rightCenterPanel.getChildren().add(table);

     RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(TreeManagedBean.rightCenterForm);
```

I am looking for equivalent of the following which can be added in backing bean:

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{myBean.selectItem}"/>
```

Also is it possible to add single and double mouse click event listeners for dataTable in the backing bean without adding any " < p:ajax event" in the xhtml file?

Comment: 1 Question per question please... _"Also is it possible to add single and double mouse click event listeners for dataTable in the backing bean without adding any " < p:ajax event" in the xhtml file?"_ This is a new question. And please explain in that new question what kind of listeners you want. Pure client-side javascript?

Answer (score 2):

> I am looking for equivalent of the following which can be added in backing bean:

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{agentBean.selectItem}"/>
```

Use **AjaxBehavior** like this:

```
import javax.el.ExpressionFactory;
import javax.el.MethodExpression;
import org.primefaces.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehavior;
import org.primefaces.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl;

final FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
final ExpressionFactory ef = application.getExpressionFactory();
final MethodExpression me = ef.createMethodExpression(fc.getELContext(),
     "#{agentBean.selectItem}", String.class, new Class[0]);
final MethodExpression meArg = ef.createMethodExpression(fc.getELContext(),
     "#{agentBean.selectItem}", String.class, new Class[]{SelectEvent.class});
final AjaxBehavior ajaxBehavior = new AjaxBehavior();
ajaxBehavior.addAjaxBehaviorListener(new AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl(me, meArg));
dt.addClientBehavior("rowSelect", ajaxBehavior);
```

---

Provide an **event handler** method in your agentBean class:

```
public void selectItem(final SelectEvent event) {}
```

It will be called when a table row gets selected.

**How it works**

The event `rowSelect` gets linked to the AjaxBehavior on the DataTable. The AjaxBehavior registers a Listener which has the MethodExpression configured to call the `agentBean.selectItem` event handler method.

Comment: Thanks but rowSelect listener is not being called:
`FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
  ExpressionFactory ef = application.getExpressionFactory();
  ELContext elc = fc.getELContext();
MethodExpression me = ef.createMethodExpression(elc,
        "#{agentBean.onRowSelect}", String.class, new Class[0]);
  AjaxBehavior ajaxBehavior = new AjaxBehavior();
  ajaxBehavior.addAjaxBehaviorListener(new AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl(me, null));
  table.addClientBehavior("rowSelect", ajaxBehavior);

public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event){
// Output message
}'

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Do you adopt the argument myBean.selectItem to your environment?

Comment: I modified your code slightly so that  "#{agentBean.onRowSelect}" is used as the function to be called when a row is selected

MethodExpression me = ef.createMethodExpression(elc, "#{agentBean.onRowSelect}", String.class, new Class[0]);

 table.addClientBehavior("rowSelect", ajaxBehavior);

Comment: It still does not work - I copied you code  apart from calling event handler method "selectItem" and not "onSelect" because MethodExpression is "#{agentBean.selectItem}".

Comment: @amah `selectItem` is correct in your case, I edit the answer. See further explanation. "still does not work" is too vague ;.)

Comment: Thanks for your response. The selectItem event handler method is not being called when I select a table row.

Comment: @amah Help is impossible if you dont provide the code you have trouble with in your question as a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).